# Creating the ball to spawn randomly

Tags: oop, pygame, pong

I am fairly new to Object-Oriented Programming, but I have this Pong game, all I am looking to add to it is have the ball spawn randomly. Not asking for anyone to write my code for me, just looking for a little push in the right direction.

```
 import pygame, sys, random
 from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
WINDOWWIDTH = 620
WINDOWHEIGHT = 440
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Pong')

pygame.font.init()
FPS = 60

  class Player(object):
     def __init__(self, x, y, padWid, padHei):
            self.x, self.y = 0, WINDOWHEIGHT/2
            self.speed = 3
            self.padWid, self.padHei = 8, 64
            self.score = 0
            self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font("imagine_font.ttf", 64)

    def scoring(self):
            scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
            windowSurface.blit(scoreBlit, (32, 16))
            if self.score == 10:
                    print ("player 1 wins!")
                    exit()

    def movement(self):
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                    self.y -= self.speed
            elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
                    self.y += self.speed

            if self.y <= 0:
                    self.y = 0
            elif self.y >= WINDOWHEIGHT-64:
                    self.y = WINDOWHEIGHT-64

    def draw(self):
            pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, self.padWid, self.padHei))

    class Enemy(Player):
    def __init__(self, x, y, padWid, padHei):
            self.x, self.y = WINDOWWIDTH-8, WINDOWHEIGHT/2
            self.speed = 3
            self.padWid, self.padHei = 8, 64
            self.score = 0
            self.scoreFont = pygame.font.Font("imagine_font.ttf", 64)

    def scoring(self):
            scoreBlit = self.scoreFont.render(str(self.score), 1, (255, 255, 255))
            windowSurface.blit(scoreBlit, (WINDOWHEIGHT+92, 16))
            if self.score == 10:
                    print ("Player 2 wins!")
                    exit()

    def movement(self):
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                    self.y -= self.speed
            elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    self.y += self.speed

            if self.y <= 0:
                    self.y = 0
            elif self.y >= WINDOWHEIGHT-64:
                    self.y = WINDOWHEIGHT-64

    def draw(self):
           pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, self.padWid, self.padHei))


   class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, size):
            self.x, self.y = WINDOWWIDTH/2, WINDOWHEIGHT/2
            self.speed_x = -3
            self.speed_y = 3
            self.size = 8

    def movement(self):
            self.x += self.speed_x
            self.y += self.speed_y

            #wall col
            if self.y <= 0:
                    self.speed_y *= -1
            elif self.y >= WINDOWHEIGHT-self.size:
                    self.speed_y *= -1

            if self.x <= 0:
                    self.__init__(WINDOWWIDTH/2, WINDOWHEIGHT/2, 8)
                    enemy.score += 1
            elif self.x >= WINDOWWIDTH-self.size:
                    self.__init__(WINDOWWIDTH/2, WINDOWHEIGHT/2, 8)
                    self.speed_x = 3
                    player.score += 1

            for n in range(-self.size, player.padHei):
                    if self.y == player.y + n:
                            if self.x <= player.x + player.padWid:
                                    self.speed_x *= -1
                                    break
                    n += 1
            for n in range(-self.size, enemy.padHei):
                    if self.y == enemy.y + n:
                            if self.x >= enemy.x - enemy.padWid:
                                    self.speed_x *= -1
                                    break
                    n += 1
    def draw(self):

       pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, 8, 8))



def main():

global  balls, BALLSIZE, windowSurface, player, ball, enemy, mainClock, FPS
player = Player('16', '2', '8', '64')
ball = Ball('2', '2', '8')
enemy = Enemy('-16', '2', '8' , '64')

while True:
    #process
    for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            print ("Game exited by user")
                            exit()

    ball.movement()
    player.movement()
    enemy.movement()

    windowSurface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    ball.draw()
    player.draw()
    player.scoring()
    enemy.draw()
    enemy.scoring()

    pygame.display.flip()
    mainClock.tick(FPS)

   main()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you please edit to a [mcve]?

Comment: My question is that every time the ball is drawn throughout the game loop whether at the start, or after a person scores I am trying to get the ball to have a random position upon spawn and not always be drawn in the middle of the window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ball to spawn randomly, use pygame.draw.circle() to draw the ping pong ball.

To generate it randomly, import Math, and then for pygame.draw.circle() 3rd argument put

(Math.randint(1, Screen.width), Math.randint(1, Screen.height))

Here is docs:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle

Comment: Does this answer your question @James N ?

Comment: Instead of Screen.width and Screen.height, put in your variables: WINDOWWIDTH and WINDOWHEIGHT

Comment: thank you for your guidance, I keep getting an error code saying the math module does not have an attribute for randint. Maybe I don't have something defined correctly.

Comment: sorry. you have to import ->random<- not math. And from there do random.randint